# Generic dictionary - possible locking issue?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Specific Answers Only Please! I'm decently familiar with the better(best) practices around collection locking, thread safety etc. Just want some answers / ideas around this specific scenario.

We have some legacy code of the type:

```
public class GodObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _signals;

    //bunch of methods accessing the dictionary

    private void SampleMethod1()
    {
        lock(_signals)
        {
            //critical code section 1
        }
    }

    public void SampleMethod2()
    {
        lock(_signals)
        {
            //critical code section 2
        }
    }
}
```

All access to the dictionary is inside such lock statements. We're getting some bugs which could be explained if the locking was not explicitly working - meaning 2 or more threads getting simultaneous access to the dictionary.

So my question is this - is there any scenario where the critical sections could be simultaneously accessed by multiple threads?? To me, it should not be possible, since the reference is readonly, it's not as though the object could be changing, and most of the issues around the lock() are around deadlocks rather than syncronization not happening. But maybe i'm missing some nuance or something glaring?

This is running in a long running windows service .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Can you reference what the error statements you are getting indicate? That might be helpful in determining the error, or if you could expound on the contents of your critical sections.

Comment: Odds are some caller is calling multiple methods of `GodObject` with the expectation that no other methods are run between them, and that expectation is violated.

Comment: A `static` might bite you in the tail.

Comment: You've not talked about what are the problems you're experiencing. and answer for your question is **no**, `Monitor.Enter` will allow only one thread to execute critical section till `Monitor.Exit` is called. That's what lock statement does internally.

Comment: Please explain the problems you are having, you mention deadlocks,  do you know the series of event that lead to one? Also are there any other methods that use `_signals` (even for read only access)? Right now, as written, your code cannot deadlock nor have thread read/write issues, but you removed too many details so we can't tell you where your problem is.

Comment: Could any of your methods be leaking the dictionary outside the GodObject class?

Comment: @scott-chamberlain - Thanks. I just wanted clarity on whether there is some edge case with lock/Monitor or some funky thing with generics / dictionary that might be causing troubles. In the production code, there are exactly 3 such methods, and the dictionary is touched only inside those lock statements, and the issues are not around deadlocks but around the locks "possibly not working". I was just eliminating the "impossible" :). For anyone interested, this is a piece of a filewatcher used for filtering multiple events raised by the .net filewatcher.

Comment: Well if you use locks incorrectly it is very possible for them to "not work"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three problems I can imagine occurring outside the code you posted:

- Somebody might access the dictionary without locking on it.  Using `lock` on an object will prevent anyone else from using `lock` on the same object at the same time, but it won't do anything to prevent other threads from using the object without locking on it.  Note that because it would not have been overly difficult to have written `Dictionary` [and for that matter `List`] in such a way as to allow safe simultaneous use by multiple readers and one writer that only adds information, some people may assume that read methods don't need locking.  Unfortunately, that assumption is false: Microsoft could have added such thread safety fairly cheaply, but didn't.
- As Servy suggested, someone might be assuming that the the collection won't change between calls to two independent methods.
- If some code which acquires a lock assumes a collection isn't going to change while the lock is held, but then calls some outside method while holding the lock, it's possible that the outside method could change the object despite the lock being held.

Unless the object which owns the dictionary keeps all references to itself, so that no outside code ever gets a reference to the dictionary, I think the first of these problems is perhaps the most likely.  The other two problems can also occur sometimes, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer supercat. I just wanted clarity on whether there is some edge case with lock/Monitor or some funky thing with generics / dictionary that might be causing troubles. In the production code, there are exactly 3 such methods, and the dictionary is touched only inside those lock statements, and the issues are not around deadlocks but around the locks "possibly not working". I was just eliminating the "impossible" :) .For anyone interested, this is a piece of a filewatcher used for filtering multiple events raised by the .net filewatcher.